In windows 10 dark mode, windows file explorer's status bas stays white
In windows 10 dark mode, windows file explorer's status bas stays white, the font however switches to white from black, so it becomes close to invisible. Check the screenshot below.

I had tried Uxthemepatcher in the past when dark mode was not there After uninstall I executed sfc /scannow, which repaired the DLLs:
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013a Hashes for file member [l:11]'themeui.dll' do not match.
 Expected: {l:32 ml:33 b:413d9bfadabc09fccb2bdfc99ca4369b87520755b609254905331f8fbeeb06cc}.
 Actual: {l:32 b:b39636aa5734009fa7d707e8ab4de587be21b7c77096509e8e6fb98c055b1b41}.
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013b [SR] Repairing file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\\themeui.dll from store
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013c [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013d [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:23:56, Info                  CSI    0000013e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:23:57, Info                  CSI    0000013f [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:23:57, Info                  CSI    00000140 [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:23:57, Info                  CSI    00000141 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:23:59, Info                  CSI    00000142 CSIPERF - FilePI Queue 292ms
2024-07-26 12:23:59, Info                  CSI    00000143 Hashes for file member [l:10]'UXInit.dll' do not match.
 Expected: {l:32 ml:33 b:124cb2f9819f673f46cc976d511740f0d5bd4f1f25e45b7a4ff3d2047b709373}.
 Actual: {l:32 b:752901750c0dfc9f456111cb163731df3a8575302d2ee86753701c7ff6b16f29}.
2024-07-26 12:23:59, Info                  CSI    00000144 [SR] Repairing file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\\UXInit.dll from store
2024-07-26 12:23:59, Info                  CSI    00000145 [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:24:00, Info                  CSI    00000146 [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:24:00, Info                  CSI    00000147 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:24:01, Info                  CSI    00000148 [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:24:01, Info                  CSI    00000149 [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:24:01, Info                  CSI    0000014a [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:24:01, Info                  CSI    0000014b [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    0000014c [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    0000014d [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    0000014e [SR] Verify complete
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    0000014f [SR] Verifying 100 components
2024-07-26 12:24:02, Info                  CSI    00000150 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2024-07-26 12:24:04, Info                  CSI    00000151 CSIPERF - FilePI Queue 185ms
2024-07-26 12:24:04, Info                  CSI    00000152 [SR] Verify complete

But still it is like this. Tried changing themes, changing light and dark mode & restarting system multiple times
Also tried SFC, this time it shows no modified DLLs

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violation

